# How to put base content in derived component?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have base component with basic html content and derived component which adds decorations to it. But now I realized I don't know how to make blazor put base content within derived component. I am looking in my case for something like this:

```
<div>
<span>my derived decoration</span>
@base_content
</div>
```

How to tell Blazor to put "here" the base content?

Comment: There's a similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73114009/blazor-wasm-inheritance-does-not-render-mark-up-from-inherited-class - see my answer for various ways to inheritance in Blazor components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your derived components `.razor` file include a call to `base.BuildRenderTree(__builder)` .

An example:

```
@inherits YourBaseComponent

<div>
<span>my derived decoration</span>

@{
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}

</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks, looks odd, but works :-)